# Limiting .NET Class to single object instance on computer boundary => "inter-process singleton"

Tags: c#, .net, interprocess

I want to have one object of some .NET class used by multiple processes on same computer.

Having Application domains, it is not easily possible to move across that boundary, but memory-mapped files in .NET 4.0 should ease that task in some way.

Until .NET 4.0 comes in final release...
Is it possible to make some kind of "inter-process singleton" in C#?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can create a .Net Remoting singleton in one process, and expose it to the other processes running on the same machine via Remoting...

EDIT:   in .Net 2.x,  you need to use a Remoting solution, but in .Net 3.x or later (wherer WCF is Available) this same funcctionality *may be* available using WCF (Check it out)...

Comment: This should be done via WCF, and not Remoting. Remoting has been deprecated in favor of WCF.

Comment: @John, Thanks, I confess Im not as familiar with details of WCF as I should be...  where I have been working, I'm only just been able to use CLR 3.x or WCF stuff..  learning more about it now

Comment: With requirements as given, I do not think it is doable via WCF. .NET Remoting will ensure that object identity is preserved at all times, while WCF will not. Also, "deprecation" of Remoting should be taken with a grain of salt - it's simply a very different technology from WCF in its design principles, and as such, there are situations where one or the other simply does better.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to use global mutex.

[Threading in C#](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.aspx#_Mutex) has a nice example (copied below for convenience) on how to use named mutex to enusure only one instance of an application can run on a machine.

You can expand this example to ensure there is only one instance of an object as well.

```
class OneAtATimePlease {
  // Use a name unique to the application (eg include your company URL)
  static Mutex mutex = new Mutex (false, "oreilly.com OneAtATimeDemo");

  static void Main() {
    // Wait 5 seconds if contended – in case another instance
    // of the program is in the process of shutting down.

    if (!mutex.WaitOne (TimeSpan.FromSeconds (5), false)) {
      Console.WriteLine ("Another instance of the app is running. Bye!");
      return;
    }
    try {
      Console.WriteLine ("Running - press Enter to exit");
      Console.ReadLine();
    }
    finally { mutex.ReleaseMutex(); }
  }
}
```

There is one more thing you may need to pay attention.

When *using named mutex on a server that is running in terminal services*, a named mutex can have two level of visibility, **Global** to all the sessions (name prefixed with "`Global\`") or **Local** to the terminal server session (name prefixed with "`Local\`", it will be default if no prefix is specified).

You can find more details on Mutex in [MSDN: Mutex Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex.aspx).

Comment: this code prevents second process to create new object, but doesn't give him reference to one that already exists. Any solution for that?

Also, thanx for your time...

Comment: I would recommend WCF for inter-process communication. In general, NetNamedPipeBinding is a good choice for inter-process communication within a machine.

Answer (score 0):

Install your `.net` dll in the global assembly cache. Then it can be referenced by any application on the computer.

Comment: Pretty sure he means theinstance and not the definition.

Comment: Exactly, I need more processes to use same *object*, not same class.