# How to implement a singleton .NET component, for use by multiple processes?

Tags: .net, multithreading, interop, singleton, multiprocessing

I would like to implement a component in .NET, and consume it in COM-aware clients via COM interop.

I would like this component to be a singleton across all *processes* that use it.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249743/limiting-net-class-to-single-object-instance-on-computer-boundary-inter-proc) thread suggests using WCF/remoting but doesn't go into much detail. Is there a good reference/example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remoting is a relic of the past and has been replaced by WCF.

You need to implement a WCF service and set the instancing mode to [Single](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.instancecontextmode.aspx).

I suggest you expose it as a Named Pipe service and host it on Windows service. A word of caution, however, if it starts giving you problems with [Named Pipe hardening](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb757001.aspx), you might have to use TCP binding.

Answer (score 0):

Why not create a windows service that the COM component communicates with? The COM is the interface that all your users work with while the service contains the actual logic.

Comment: Virtual -1. No way!! Come on - COM is dead :)

Comment: OP requested COM, not me. Or have I misinterpreted the question?